# How to add link_to block with spans inside it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to create a link_to tag for the syntax below.

```
<li class="bg-master-lighter">
  <a href="#" class="clearfix">
    <span class="pull-left">Logout</span>
    <span class="pull-right"><i class="pg-power"></i></span>
   </a>
 </li>
```

I am using devise gem so i am trying to add a logout method to the link but my styling goes like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Devise manual](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template) the link should look like this:

```
<li class="bg-master-lighter">
  <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "clearfix" do %>
    <span class="pull-left">Logout</span>
    <span class="pull-right"><i class="pg-power"></i></span>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: i needed to add devise logout method " destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete where should i add that in the above code?

Comment: @maithreyareddy: I adjusted my answer.